# Copy file from target folder of one module to another target folder module

Tags: apache, maven

I have two modules A and B. After maven create the artifact of A, this one generate a a.conf file that I need in my integration test on B. I would like to copy this a.conf file from the A target folder to the B target folder, to be deleted from B after finish the process.

So far I make it works with Maven resource plugin. But only works if I move the conf file from resource A to resource B folders, and not from target to target folder.

The ant plugin seems like not offer me the possibility to copy files from module to another.

Can anybody please suggest me a way to do what I want to accomplish here?.

Regards.

Comment: You should consider MavenProjects as isolated, in general you should only share the artifacts as dependencies, so don't try to access other projects. What's so special in `a.conf` that you can't generate it in project B?

Comment: A file that is generated when maven create the artifact